# Mule - queue files only one file is passed through flow at any one time if queue contains multiple file

Tags: mule

I have a Mule project with 8 flow that is listening file form different locations in wmq. This wmq is further attached with java transformer and more for further processing.  Is there a way I can restrict my flow from only processing one file at a time if two files or more than two files are there in the same queue.

Essentially, the way I'd like my application to work is if two files are dropped at the same time, Mule picks up one, processes it, and only when the flow has finished start processing the next file.

Right now, what happening is, flow is picking all the files at once before completing the whole process. I am using one-way pattern in wmq. Please see the link for the one part of the flow which i have created

[How to make compatible wmq with java code in MULE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23925807/how-to-make-compatible-wmq-with-java-code-in-mule?noredirect=1#comment36882342_23925807)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the queue you want to consume serially, make sure that:

- The `wmq:inbound-endpoint` is configured by a `wmq:connector` that has `numberOfConsumers="1"` (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+WMQ+Transport+Reference)
- The flow that contains this endpoint has `processingStrategy="synchronous"` (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies)